# Как генерировать только 14 строчек

Tags: python, python-3.x

Всем привет,как сделать что бы скрипт генерировал только 14 строчек? иногда бывает что 13 генерирует мне нужно строго 14.

```
import datetime as DT
import random

date_fmt = '%m/%d/%Y:%H:%M'
step = DT.timedelta(minutes=5)
start_date = DT.datetime.strptime('4/1/2022:08:00', date_fmt)
last_date = DT.datetime.strptime('4/2/2022:8:00', date_fmt)



def create_time(start_date, last_date):
    timatable = []
    a = 1
    while start_date <= last_date:
        print(start_date, a)
        timatable.append(start_date)
        step2 = DT.timedelta(hours=random.uniform(1.5, 2))
        start_date += step
        start_date += step2
        a += 1

    return timatable
create_time(start_date,last_date)
```

Результат программы

```
2022-04-01 08:00:00 1
2022-04-01 10:04:36.522766 2
2022-04-01 11:48:02.639554 3
2022-04-01 13:38:39.613229 4
2022-04-01 15:43:19.774118 5
2022-04-01 17:21:20.608240 6
2022-04-01 19:10:34.335244 7
2022-04-01 20:49:17.607405 8
2022-04-01 22:40:55.065865 9
2022-04-02 00:19:10.065549 10
2022-04-02 02:21:46.418680 11
2022-04-02 04:14:05.954035 12
2022-04-02 06:13:24.821632 13
```

Comment: какие входные данные? всегда ли только одни сутки? Должно ли первое значение быть равным start_date?

Comment: Ну поскольку у вас там `random` у вас теоретически и другие варианты могут быть. В итоге то вы что хотите - сделать внутри периода строго 14 отсчётов времени, но при этом чтобы они всё-равно были случайными?

Comment: Для начала можете попробовать ограничить в `random.uniform(1.5, 2)` значения в зависимости от того, сколько осталось часов в интервале `last_date - start_date`, ну то есть не `2`, а `min(2, число_часов_между_ласт_и_старт)`

Answer (score 1):

Я бы перевел диапазон в итератор (юникс-время, например, range (start, stop)) и взял бы оттуда 14 значений (random.choices).

```
import datetime as DT
import time
import random

date_fmt = '%m/%d/%Y:%H:%M'
start_date = DT.datetime.strptime('4/1/2022:08:00', date_fmt)
last_date = DT.datetime.strptime('4/2/2022:8:00', date_fmt)

start = int(time.mktime(start_date.timetuple())) # unix-time - начало
end = int(time.mktime(last_date.timetuple())) # unix-time - конец

timatable = random.choices(range(start, end), k=14) # 14 значений из указанного промежутка
```

Обратите внимание, что результат НЕ СОРТИРОВАН. Поэтому, если данные нужны хронологически, то нужно отсортировать. Ну и привести в нужный вид, потому что сейчас в `timatable` тоже юникс-время, а не datetime.

Comment: Примерно так for i in range (14):?

Comment: Нет, совсем не так. Посмотрите справку по функции random.choice

Comment: ой, не choice, а choices

Comment: добавил пример кода